# Apache POI logging, does not log anything

Tags: java, logging, apache-poi

I'm trying to log out to help my find the error, but using the [information from the apache poi page](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) does not log anything, I expected something to happen in the console.

```
  System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.util.POILogger", "org.apache.poi.util.SystemOutLogger");
  System.setProperty("poi.log.level", POILogger.INFO + "");

/*...
some more code
...*/

            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                evaluator.setDebugEvaluationOutputForNextEval(true);
                CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(valueCell);
                value = cellValue.getNumberValue();
                break;
```

The underlying issue is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid sheetIndex: -1.
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.<init>(SheetRefEvaluator.java:36)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext.createExternSheetRefEvaluator(OperationEvaluationContext.java:132)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext.createExternSheetRefEvaluator(OperationEvaluationContext.java:84)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext.getRef3DEval(OperationEvaluationContext.java:309)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.getEvalForPtg(WorkbookEvaluator.java:634)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:505)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval.getInnerValueEval(LazyRefEval.java:43)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromRef(OperandResolver.java:179)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.dereferenceResult(WorkbookEvaluator.java:570)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:521)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval.getInnerValueEval(LazyRefEval.java:43)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromRef(OperandResolver.java:179)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:36)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:503)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Sumif.accumulate(Sumif.java:95)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Sumif.sumMatchingCells(Sumif.java:83)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Sumif.eval(Sumif.java:72)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Sumif.evaluate(Sumif.java:65)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Var2or3ArgFunction.evaluate(Var2or3ArgFunction.java:36)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:503)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval.getInnerValueEval(LazyRefEval.java:43)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromRef(OperandResolver.java:179)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.RelationalOperationEval.evaluate(RelationalOperationEval.java:64)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:503)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval.getInnerValueEval(LazyRefEval.java:43)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromRef(OperandResolver.java:179)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:36)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:503)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getValue(AreaEvalBase.java:131)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.MultiOperandNumericFunction.collectValues(MultiOperandNumericFunction.java:151)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.MultiOperandNumericFunction.getNumberArray(MultiOperandNumericFunction.java:128)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.MultiOperandNumericFunction.evaluate(MultiOperandNumericFunction.java:90)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:503)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval.getInnerValueEval(LazyRefEval.java:43)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromRef(OperandResolver.java:179)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.UnaryPlusEval.evaluate(UnaryPlusEval.java:38)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed1ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed1ArgFunction.java:33)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:503)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval.getInnerValueEval(LazyRefEval.java:43)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromRef(OperandResolver.java:179)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:62)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.dereferenceResult(WorkbookEvaluator.java:570)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:521)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Sumif.accumulate(Sumif.java:95)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Sumif.sumMatchingCells(Sumif.java:83)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Sumif.eval(Sumif.java:72)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Sumif.evaluate(Sumif.java:65)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Var2or3ArgFunction.evaluate(Var2or3ArgFunction.java:36)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:503)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:702)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Sumif.accumulate(Sumif.java:95)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Sumif.sumMatchingCells(Sumif.java:83)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Sumif.eval(Sumif.java:72)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Sumif.evaluate(Sumif.java:65)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Var2or3ArgFunction.evaluate(Var2or3ArgFunction.java:36)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:503)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:205)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:268)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluate(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:121)
```

Comment: Have you checked the source code of the method throwing the exception, to see if it has any logging in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't get the 'SystemOutLogger' to work either - this is not helped by the fact that the Apache POI documentation for how to enable logging seems to have disappeared.

I managed to find an old link with "Way Back Machine":

http://web.archive.org/web/20070701061428/http://poi.apache.org/utils/logging.html

I am using 'log4j' for the rest of my project, so I have already got a log4j.properties file which looks like this:

```
Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

The link states that 'commons-logging' although not required at compile-time: for this task it should be included at runtime; so I added this to my Maven project file (I have included log4j and poi itself here for reference also)

```
<project>
[...]
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>   
</dependencies>
[...]
</project>
```

Then in my project I programmatically set the System Property to redirect to the commons logger (which should then pick up on the log4j logging mechanism):

```
public class ExcelOpener {
    private static final Logger oLog = Logger.getLogger(ExcelOpener.class );
    {
        System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.util.POILogger", "org.apache.poi.util.CommonsLogger" );
    }
[...]
```

This works for me - I can now see the code is logging at DEBUG level: for instance:

```
2015-10-07 15:06:07 DEBUG PackageRelationshipCollection:88 - Parsing relationship: /xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels
2015-10-07 15:06:07 DEBUG PackageRelationshipCollection:88 - Parsing relationship: /xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.rels
2015-10-07 15:06:07 DEBUG PackageRelationshipCollection:88 - Parsing relationship: /_rels/.rels
2015-10-07 15:06:08 DEBUG XSSFFactory:88 - using default POIXMLDocumentPart for http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/printerSettings
```

Comment: Didn't get it to work unfortunately, nothing logs :/

Comment: Hi Vixen: interesting - are you using the same version of POI as I am ? Are you using log4j like I am (and if so: do YOUR logging work properly?) and if you are using Maven/Ant etc - make sure you 'clean/build' your project - so make sure log4j file is up-to-date.